# Resizing dynamic string array

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

I am trying to resize a dynamically allocated string array; here's the code!

```
void resize_array() {
    size_t newSize = hash_array_length + 100;
    string* newArr = new string[newSize];

    fill_n(hash_array,newSize,"0"); //fills arrays with zeros

    memcpy( newArr, hash_array, hash_array_length * sizeof(string) );

    hash_array_length = newSize;
    delete [] hash_array;
    hash_array = newArr;
}
```

unfortunately it isn't working and gives a segmentation fault. any idea why? this is basically a linear probing hash table where the element gets inserted wherever there is a 0 hence I use fill_n to fill the newly created array with 0's. any help please?

Comment: Could you tell us what language you're using here and in which line the segmentation fault occurs? Thanks.

Comment: The language I'm using is C++, and I can't determine the line on which the segmentation fault occurs, I'm using dev-c++ as a compiler and I guess there's something wrong with the debugger.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to test for unused entries using [`std::string::empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) instead of filling and testing for a magic value of `"0"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
memcpy( newArr, hash_array, hash_array_length * sizeof(string) );
```

This line is extremely dangerous, std::string is not a plain old data type,
you can't make sure that memcpy could initialize it correctly, it may cause
undefined behavior, one of the most nasty behavior of c++(or programming).

Besides, there are a better and safer(in most of the times) solution to create
a dynamic string array in c++, just use vector

```
//create a dynamic string array with newSize and initialize them with "0"
//in your case, I don't think you need to initialize it with "0"
std::vector<std::string> newArr(newSize, "0");
```

if the hash_array has the same type as newArr(std::vector)
The way of copy it is very easy.

c++98

```
std::copy(hash_array.begin(), hash_array.end(), newArr.begin());
```

c++11

```
std::copy(std::begin(hash_array), std::end(hash_array), std::begin(newArr));
```

Better treat c++ as a new language, it has too many things are different from c.
Besides, there are a lot of decent free IDE, like code::blocks and QtCreator
devc++ is a almost dead project.

If you are new to c++, c++ primer 5 is a good book to start.

Comment: will this do the same thing as the previous memcpy line? I really have never done C, started with C++.

Comment: no, this code only create dynamic array of string and initialize it with "0".I don't know how to copy the hash_array to the newArr before I know the type of hash_array.

Answer (score 1):

If `string` is actually an `std::string` (and probably even if it isn't) then this will crash. You are creating a new array of strings, copying the old string classes over the top, and then freeing the old strings. But if the string class contains internal pointers to allocated memory this will result in a double free because all you are doing is copying the internal pointers - not making new memory allocations.

Think about it like this; imagine you had the following class:

```
class foo
{
    char* bar;

    foo() { bar = malloc(100); }
    ~foo() { free(bar);
};

foo* ptr1 = new foo;
foo* ptr2 = new foo;
memcpy(ptr2, ptr1, sizeof(foo*));
delete ptr1;
```

At this point, `ptr2->bar` points to the same memory that `ptr1->bar` did, but `ptr1` and the memory it held has been freed

The best solution would be to use a `std::vector` because this handles the resizing automatically and you don't need to worry about copying arrays at all. But if you want to persist with your current approach, you need to change the `memcpy` call to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hash_array_length; ++i)
{
    newArr[i] = hash_array[i];
}
```

Rather than just copying the memory this will call the class's copy constructor and make a proper copy of its contents.

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems really helpful and actually makes sense! :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the culprit is `memcpy` call. `string` is complicated type which manages the char array by pointers (just as you are doing right now). Normally copying string is done using assignment operator, which for string also copies its own array. But memcpy simply copies byte-per-byte the pointer, and delete[] also deletes the array managed by string. Now the other string uses deleted string array, which is BAAAD.

You can use std::copy instead of memcpy, or even better yet, use std::vector, which is remedy to most of your dynamic memory handling problems ever.